# What type of critical point is (0,0) in the following function?

Tags: calculus

Studying for an exam, I was given the following and had to tell what type of critical point $(0,0)$ is. The answer is "Not a saddle and not a minimum or maximum point".
I got that its supposed to be a saddle point which is why I'm confused.

$ f(x,y)\in C^2 , T_2(x,y)= 3+2x+0.5x^2-xy-y^2$ Around $(0,0)$.

My efforts:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYud7.jpg

Comment: What is $T_2$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Taylor polynomial function up to second degree

Comment: But why it has linear terms? So it's not a critical point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $T_2$ is the Taylor expansion up to degree 2 around $(0,0)$, it follows that $\nabla f(0,0)=(2,0)$ so it is NOT a critical point.

Recall that $T_2(x,y)=f(0,0)+\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (x,y) +(x,y)H_f(0,0)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$